# Thread in fragment with setRetainInstance(true)

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, fragment

I have a fragment with a thread inside it, starting in its onCreate method.

After thread finishes his work i need to send a message to the activity (myActivity) through the "clickButtonOperation".

This is the onCreate() method of my fragment:

```
public class HolderFragment extends My_Fragment{

private Thread myThread;

.
.
.

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);
    printf("MyActivity attached is: "+myActivity);

    myThread=new Thread(new Runnable(){


        @Override
        public void run() {

            int i=0;
            while (i<3){

                printf("Working...");
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
            }

            myActivity.clickButtonOperation(new Object[]{

                    HolderFragment.this.toString()
            });
        }
    });

    myThread.start();
}
```

onCreateView returns NULL.

My question is:
Is it guaranteed that my "clickButonOperation" gets called after the new activity has been attached? or could this method be called before this process?

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION:**

I created a custom Thread class:

```
public abstract class My_Thread extends Thread {

private boolean runnable=true;
private boolean paused=false;
private Object[] arguments;
private My_ThreadHolder myHolder;

protected void onPostExecute(Object[] arguments){

    while(paused);
    runnable=false;
}

protected abstract void execute(Object[] arguments);

protected void notifyUpdate(){

    while (paused);
}

protected boolean isRunnable(){

    return runnable;
}

public void setArguments(Object[] arguments){

    this.arguments=arguments;
}

public Object[] getArguments() {

    return arguments;
}

public final void run(){

    while (runnable){

        execute(arguments);
        onPostExecute(arguments);
    }
}

public void attach(My_ThreadHolder holder){

    myHolder=holder;
}


public My_ThreadHolder getHolder() {

    return myHolder;
}

public void startThread(){

    runnable=true;
    start();
}

public void stopThread(){

    runnable=false;
}

public void pauseThread(){

    paused=true;
    printf("Thread paused");
}

public void resumeThread(){

    paused=false;
    printf("Thread resumed");
}
}
```

And created these two:

```
public class My_ThreadHolder extends My_Fragment{

private TestThread myThread;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);
    printf("MyActivity attached is: "+myActivity);
    myThread=new TestThread();
    myThread.attach(this);
    myThread.startThread();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (myThread!=null)myThread.resumeThread();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    myThread.pauseThread();
}

protected void onNotifyUpdateReceived(Object[] arguments){

    myActivity.clickButtonOperation(arguments);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {return null;}

@Override
protected void setGraphics(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
}

class TestThread extends My_Thread{


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object[] arguments) {
    super.onPostExecute(arguments);

    printf("Thread finished");
}

@Override
protected void execute(Object[] arguments) {

    int i=0;
    while(i<3){

        printf("Working...");

        try {

            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i++;

        Object[] myArguments= new Object[2];
        myArguments[0]=0;
        myArguments[1]=i;
        setArguments(myArguments);
        notifyUpdate();
    }
}

@Override
protected void notifyUpdate() {

    super.notifyUpdate();

    getHolder().onNotifyUpdateReceived(getArguments());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot touch the UI from a background thread.. you need to use `runOnUiThread` method from `Activity` class, something like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);
    printf("MyActivity attached is: "+myActivity);

    myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 3) {
                printf("Working...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
            }

            myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     myActivity.clickButtonOperation(new Object[]{
                         HolderFragment.this.toString()
                     });
                 }
            });
        }
    });

    myThread.start();
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, by the way my intent is not to touch the ui, but simply notify the mainactivity to do something.. should i use always this approach?

Comment: The code above with setRetainInstance(true) can create memory leak problems. You need to handle the mActivity properly. You are only allowed to use Threads?

Comment: Yes, i will check out with AsyncTask, but now i must work with threads...
Would you suggest any smart way to work with this without going crazy?